# Bedrock beta: Zombie Piglin over-world spawning requirements

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm building a gold farm in the newest Minecraft beta for the bedrock edition (1.16.0.60) and I've googled designs for gold farms. I've seen a 0 tick design but it was too laggy and spawned too many zombie piglins for me. I want to build a regular gold-farm using the random ticks to spawn piglins in portals.

I'm going to use maximum size portals (23 by 23 blocks) and I'm going to space each portal 1 block apart from other portals to take advantage of the bedrock edition's spawn mechanics.

My problem is I don't know how big to make the farm and the mechanics that I know from java edition are entirely different. I can't find any information for the following questions on the Minecraft wikis, or any popular YouTube videos on building these types of farms:

**Size questions:**

- How high can the farm be? in java edition I remember a 32 block
  spherical range but in bedrock this seems to be completely different
  because I've seen farms on YouTube with large heights over 60 blocks
  above the afk platform.
- How wide/long can the farm be? is there a spherical or cylindrical range for piglin
  spawning?

**Spawn mechanic questions:**

- Is the range based on hostile mob spawns? (24-54 blocks). I've seen
  farms on you tube that make the     portals close to the player
  (under 24 blocks).
- What are the per tick chances of a zombie pigman spawning in the
  bedrock edition? is it the same as Java? (1/2000 on easy, 2/2000 on
  normal, 3/2000 on hard).
- Is this chance per portal block?